# Is it possible to find the nearest distance to an open set?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, elementary-set-theory

If I have some open set A, is it possible to find the nearest distance in some norm( say Frobenius) from a point outside of the set to the set? Logically I would think that I would always be able to find some value that is closer as the boundary is not in the set.

For examples sake lets take the set of matrices such that the diagonal is greater than 2, I will always be able to find some $\epsilon$ which gets my matrix closer to the matrix of diagonals greater than 2? I am unsure how to formally show/prove this.

Comment: If you define the shortest distance as an infimum (and not a minimum) then it will exist, but this it will be the same thing as the distance to the closure of $A$ (so points in the closure will be at distance $0$).

Comment: In any metric space $(X,d)$, let $x\in X$ and $Y\subseteq X,Y\ne\emptyset$. You can always define $d(x,Y):=\inf_{y∈Y}d(x,y)$, and as this infimum is of a non-empty set of real numbers (bounded by $0$ from below), it is always well-defined. Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 0):

In a metric space, the distance of a point $p$ to a nonempty subset $X$ is given by
$$
d(p,X) = \inf \{ d(p,x) : x \in X \}
$$
This distance is not necessarily attained at a point of $X$ when $X$ is not closed.